# Azure SQL - Spatial Peformance Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I've recently set up an Azure SQL Database with intentions to build high-performance spatial applications.

Unfortunately when comparing Azure SQL to an on-prem server I'm getting very poor performance when executing geospatial queries like intersections of polygon boundaries.

**Server Config:**

*On-Prem*

- SQL Server 2022
- Xeon E5-1630 CPU // 64GB 2133mhz DDR4 RAM // Samsung
  870 EVO SSD)

*Azure SQL*

- General Purpose - Serverless: Standard-series (Gen5) 80 vCore max, 80 vCore min
- Also tested the S3 100 DTU model. This not only didn't perform, but isn't feasible financially.

**Dataset:**

- [dbo].[AddressGeocodes] -> Lat, Long Points, stored as geometry.
- [dbo].[SA1_GDA2020] -> Multi-polygon geo-spatial boundaries, also in geometry

Replicated across systems (incl. clustered PK + spatial indexes with bounding boxes and auto-grid)

**Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[AddressGeocodes] GEO
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[SA1_GDA2020] SA1 ON GEO.[geom].STIntersects(SA1.[geom]) = 1
```

The estimated and actual execution plans within SSMS are identical, recognising the two clustered PKs and the spatial index.

**Results (after 60 seconds):**

- On-prem -> 68,000 Records
- Azure 80 vCores -> 17,000 Records

**Conclusion**:

*What I don't understand is within azure portal, the CPU usage is only 2% for the query.*

**Could anyone please help me understand how there is such a dramatic difference?**

There are very limited resources for spatial performance in Azure.

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Network latency? The MS-TDS protocol used to connect SSMS (and .NET/JDBC/ODBC clients) to SQL Server was designed for use in low-latency environments like LANs. It's very chatty and suffers horribly on WAN connections (even more so with mobile networks for phones and tablets). Instead of returning the results to an SSMS tab, if you spool the results into a `#temp` table are they more comparable?

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your comment!
This was a good suggestion I hadn't considered. While returning results to #temp did close the gap, on three different tests it's still operating at about half the speed of the local server :( thanks for the input tho, it's another test method I can use!

Answer (score 0):

With S3 you only have two vCores available and max degree of parallelism is one (1), all your query plans are serialized. I guess your local SQL Server has more computing power.

If you already think S3 is expensive and you cannot afford to scale up and try what service tier better adjust to the performance you are expecting, then you can try saving Lat and Long Points as varchar and convert them to geography when needed.

```
SET [GeoLocation] = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST([Longitude] 
AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + 
                CAST([Latitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)
```

Comment: I'm not following your line of reasoning on why "saving Lat and Long Points as varchar and convert them to geography when needed" would be more performant than what the OP is doing now. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Would also appreciate some clarity on this, as wouldn't this approach render spatial indexes unusable? Thanks for the input tho, will run some tests on your suggestion (Y)

Comment: They are useful if you are willing to pay more for a service tier that do not serialize the execution plan of all your queries, and scale up the service tier will make pay more. The workaround to not pay more is the solution I provided, save the data as varchar data type. Test the performance yourself, it is not bad for the price.

Comment: @BenThul. Yes it will be more performant on the service tier the database is using. The queries are using just 1 vcore. Lach will be doing test himself.